# Let user input integers until "X" is pressed Java

Tags: java

Basically what I have to do is read user input in (CUI) until the user presses x. Then display the min,max and average of the numbers the user has entered. I keep getting a InputMismatchException when I press x. I have tried a lot of different ways and that is why I may have some unnecessary code in there.

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Number;
public class taskTwo{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    boolean isX =false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String s = "x";
    s = input2.readLine();


    while(isX == false){
     if(s.equals ("x") || s.equals ("X")){
        isX = true;
    }

    int val = input.nextInt();

      if (val == 0) {
          break;
      }
      if (val < min) {
          min = val;
      }
      if (val > max) {
         max = val;
      }

      }

     if(isX == true){
      System.out.println("Min: " + min);
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);
      }




}
```

}

Comment: Do you enter anything else than the `x`? Also, don't use two objects to read from standard input. `Scanner` already has everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the while loop you are using nextInt(), obviously it will expect an integer as input. So when you are giving input x which is an string then it will fail.

So in the loop take string as input and if it is not X and is a number then convert it to int values and calculate

Answer (score 0):

s = input2.readLine(); is called outside while loop means only for first line it will check for X and loop can never be ended if fist line is not X or you entered 0.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You don't need two objects reading input. Just `input` is sufficient.

2.) You can use

```
input.hasNextInt();
```

and

```
input.hasNext();
```

to check if the input is an int or a string. Something like:

```
while(true){
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
        //do something with the integer
    }else if(input.hasNext()){
        if(input.next().toLowerCase() == "x"){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```